# Skyrim sudden FPS drop during zone transition

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

Does anyone know how to fix an issue where changing zones (immediately after loading screen appears) FPS drops to single digits. Restarting the game is a workaround but I'm looking for a long-term fix.

Comment: drops permanently or temporarily?

Comment: We need some more details on your specifications, configuration and what you have tried.

Comment: Core i7 920, GTX 560 Ti - it's not a system spec issue - I have a high speced machine. It's a permanent issue until the game is restarted or you leave the zone that spontaneously becomes affected (returning to where you just came from restores normal FPS).

Comment: I have encountered this as well and it isn't always permanent. The first time it happened it cleared up after about a minute, but recurred at the next zone change and persisted until restart. It also temporarily abates when certain menus are open, including the journal/stats/game menu and the map.

Comment: The same thing happens to me. Reinstalled my graphics drivers for my Radeon HD 6900M card, worked temporarily, then the loading zone issue began arising again. It runs on ultra-high quality for the first loading zone I am in, then when it transfers to another loading zone it drops to about 10-15 fps. Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: @Bilge - I have the exact same config, and I faced the exact same issue - I, however, had attributed it to a driver issue...

Answer (score 1):

Try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I use this in every new zone.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a fix for this issue guys. download the TES Skyrim 0.090 Patch 3 from [here](http://enbdev.com/download_en.htm), drop the contents in your skyrim folder, not the "data" folder, just where you can find your .exe.

As far as I can understand its a driver specifically for Skyrim. In fact, when you open the launcher and go to change your settings it does not say the model of your card, it says the name of the driver in question. Sorry for my bad english.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain a little more what that does? Otherwise this will be deleted for being potentially dangerous

Comment: Well as far as I can understand its a driver specifically for Skyrim. In fact, when you open the launcher and go to change your settings it does not say the model of your card, it says the name of the driver in question. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: One thing. This file is not of my making. I don't know the person that made it but he's suppose to have a reputation in Elder Scroll's mod scene. He's name is Boris Vorontsov and his website (where you can get the download from) is http://enbdev.com

Comment: Boris, who runs the ENB Series, makes custom directx dll's that try to improve performance and graphics for games that can benefit from it. The dll for Skyrim is work-in-progress and may or may not fix the problem.

Comment: @precog be careful with ENB Series, it can sometimes corrupt the whole darn sim. I had a horrid experience. I was running an fx mod, and was informed both could work together; it didn't. Uninstalling it didn't fix. It's still very much in development. The CK tools are not out yet (sometime in January... maybe) so you might want to hold off for a bit, or just keep a backup handy. Never know with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I've read somewhere that changing the AA to 2x and/OR turning it off ingame and forcing it on in your CCC fixes the stuttering issue.

A solution that **does** work is:

Going in and out of your menu screen (by spamming <kbd>esc</kbd>) 3-6 times.

That's a constant fix for me. Immersion breaking, however.

---

Also, turning off **"object fading"** in the advanced options menu in the launcher might be of influence. This is an idea of myself which I have not tested yet, but considering the fact that I heard people with the same issue complain that it happens when objects fade in made me think.

I haven't tested any of these resolutions yet. I'm at work and will try them out tonight. I have good hopes, however.