# Can I stop Skyrim slowing down after 5 minutes?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, performance

My laptop's about a year old, but I bought it at quite a high spec then so it's still fine. When I first ran Skyrim, it chose the 'high' graphics setting. At first, the game plays very smoothly, however after a few minutes it starts to slow down, and after about 5 minutes or so the game is unplayable (<5 fps).

Quitting Skyrim completely and reloading it seems to solve the problem, but only for another 5 minutes of play. I've tried turning down the graphics options to their lowest setting, but this doesn't seem to help. Is there a way to diagnose what the problem is, and fix it?

Comment: how much hard drive space do you have left?  and how much memory do you have

Comment: 75GB, 4GB respectively.

Comment: hmm... no issues there then.  Does it slow down even if you don't move at all once you enter the game world?

Comment: Is it maybe time for -> http://superuser.com/questions/352030/how-to-clean-a-fan-on-a-hp-6715s-notebook-without-taking-it-out ?

Comment: If this is a sudden drop in FPS immediately after a loading screen, you may be having the same problem described in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35783/skyrim-sudden-fps-drop-during-zone-transition).

Comment: @StupidOne its only a overheating issue if the game remains slow once he reenters the game immediately as there shouldn't have been enough time for anything to cool down yet.  If it resets back to normal speed after a restart, then its probably something else.  Having said that, a cleaning is never a bad thing.

Comment: @yx Haven't checked, I'll do a test later.

Comment: try monitoring your cpu and gpu temperature with cpuid while playing skyrim, see if they have any temperature spikes

Comment: My high end laptop is about 1½ year old now and can play it on ultra easely so i guess yours should also be able to @ least play it at high try doing a disk defragmentation get rid cookies u can also do a chkdsk and run it as a high priority in your task manager and as already mentioned try cleaning it blow the dust away also helps a ton :D

Comment: How on earth will clearing out my cookies speed up the game?!

Comment: just get rid of everything that's uselss on your pc it always helps alot same as don't store to much on your desktop.

Comment: @ronnie I must disagree with you there, it's a common misconception that lots of icons on your desktop slows your computer down (though it may be symptomatic of other causes of computer slowness!) Clearing out your startup items in `msconfig` is a much, much better way of 'speeding up' your computer!

Comment: If there's cookies inside your computer that might affect performance...

Comment: @desaivv yeah having foreign objects inside a computer is NOT the best idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked your operating temperature? It could be that your GPU/CPU is overheating, and underclocking itself to cool down, especially if it goes away after a few minutes of waiting after shutting it down.

Does it happen with other games? If not it might just be an issue with Skyrim in general (give their support line a message in that case), but if so, make sure your system isn't choked with dust and that you have proper ventilation just in case it is an overheating issue. It goes without saying that you should try to avoid multitasking when you're playing as well, in case something in the background decides to start eating CPU cycles as well.

Honestly, though, there's not a lot to diagnose on. Check your temperatures when running, maybe have a CPU/GPU monitor handy to see if anything obvious is redlining.

P.S. For those who think overheating issues take a long time to dissipate, properly ventilated stuff can cool down pretty fast, especially if it isn't generating any more heat.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue on my MacBook Pro too.  What I have experienced is that if I open all the various menus, and then save the game, it will often get better and go away after a couple of minutes.

**Notes**: The TESV Acceleration layer has helped.  However I have noticed with the latest patch (LBA) when I run without SKSE through the normal launcher I don't see it as noticeably as when I run the SKSE launcher, however frame rate is greatly improved for me once I get past the laggy patch with the SKSE/Acceleration Layer active.  Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

After you launch Skyrim, open task manager (Control+Shift+Escape) and go to processes. Select TESV.exe and set the priority to high. This should give Skyrim more processing time. I do this and the game runs smoothly for me, without doing this the game runs very slow.